# Feature toggles in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, featuretoggle

I'd like to add some "feature toggling mechanism" to my Vue application. While I have implemented a rather basic setup, I'd like to consider the techniques described in this [article by Pete Hodgson](https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html#ImplementationTechniques). Especially the aspect "Inversion of Decision" looks meaningful but I'm struggling to get an idea of how to adapt this to my Vue application.

This is what I have so far.

**config.js**

```
const yn = require("yn");

const config = {
  // Add new feature toggles here
  features: {
    myFeature: parse(
      window.myaEnv.myFeature || process.env.VUE_APP_MY_FEATURE,
      false
    ),
  },
};

function parse(value, fallback) {
  if (typeof value === "undefined") {
    return fallback;
  }
  switch (typeof fallback) {
    case "boolean":
      return yn(value);
    case "number":
      return value ? JSON.parse(value) : fallback;
    default:
      return value;
  }
}

function feature(name) {
  return config.features[name];
}

export { config };

export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.appConfig = config;
    Vue.feature = feature;

    Vue.prototype.$appConfig = config;
    Vue.prototype.$feature = feature;
  },
};
```

Then in e.g. a component I toggle the visibility like this:

```
b-button(v-if="this.$feature('myFeature')") I'm visible only if feature is enabled
```

While this is a very basic example I can imagine that feature toggles might become more complex to handle like this.

How to apply the described feature toggle techniques?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this Vue plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-feature-toggle ?

It looks promising to me and something that can help you to achieve your goal.

NOTE: I am going to implement Feature Toggle in VueJS in the next couple of months so still researching for the best approach.

UPDATE: In my case, I wasn't able to make work everything as expected using vue-feature-toggle lib, so I build a custom solution - keep feature toggles in store, and have mixin with function `isFeatureToggled(featureToggleKey)`

Answer (score 1):

you might also consider to use [Unleash](https://unleash.github.io) together with the [vue-unleash-plugin](https://github.com/crishellco/vue-unleash). This plugin requires that your project use Vuex.

PS! I am the author of Unleash, and any feedback on how we can ease the integration with Vue is welcomed.